# Search conditions on multiple tables of an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

Clients

```
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Client ID | Created                 | Client Type |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 1         | 2020-09-26 17:08:10.000 | Case        |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 2         | 2020-09-26 17:08:11.000 | Case        |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 3         | 2020-09-26 17:08:11.000 | Case        |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 4         | 2020-09-26 17:08:11.000 | Case        |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 7         | 2020-09-27 21:10:14.000 | Case        |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Assessments

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Assessment ID                        | Created                 | Client ID | Assessment Type |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| b2b200ec-9725-eb11-a813-00224808102a | 2020-11-13 10:06:49.000 | 6         | Monitoring      |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 5cb200ec-9725-eb11-a813-00224808102a | 2020-11-13 10:06:47.000 | 1         | Monitoring      |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 1ab200ec-9725-eb11-a813-00224808102a | 2020-11-13 10:06:45.000 | 2         | Monitoring      |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| c2b100ec-9725-eb11-a813-00224808102a | 2020-11-13 10:06:42.000 | 3         | Monitoring      |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 77b100ec-9725-eb11-a813-00224808102a | 2020-11-13 10:06:41.000 | 5         | Monitoring      |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Phone Calls

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| Phone Call ID                        | Created                 | Client ID |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 34910860-fdd7-ea11-a813-000d3a5a11b0 | 2020-08-06 15:56:27.000 | 0         |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 5a64b658-fdd7-ea11-a813-000d3a5a11b0 | 2020-08-06 15:56:16.000 | 9         |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 9a543238-fdd7-ea11-a813-000d3a5a11b0 | 2020-08-06 15:55:21.000 | 2         |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 2bd93432-fdd7-ea11-a813-000d3a5a11b0 | 2020-08-06 15:55:15.000 | 1         |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
| e11c73f8-fcd7-ea11-a813-000d3a5a11b0 | 2020-08-06 15:53:36.000 | 8         |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

I'd like to create a query where I get only (Phone Calls in the last 24 hours) AND (Clients = Cases) AND (Assessments = Monitoring).

My query doesn't work -- it gets only Cases Clients and only Monitoring Assessments, but it doesn't get phone calls only the last 24 hours. What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate the help.

```
SELECT p.[Client ID], COUNT(p.[Phone Call ID]) AS [Phone Calls]
--INTO ##monitoringCasesInterviewAttempts
FROM dbo.vPhonecalls AS p
    INNER JOIN dbo.vAssessments AS a ON (p.[Client ID] = a.[Client ID])
    INNER JOIN dbo.vClients AS c ON (p.[Client ID] = c.[Client ID])
WHERE p.Created >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
    AND a.[Assessment Type] = 'Monitoring'
    AND c.[Client Type] = 'Case'
GROUP BY p.[Client ID]
GO
```

I tried to create a temporary table of only phone calls in the last 24 hours (below), and the query above still gets all the phone calls. Is there something wrong with how I'm using the COUNT or GROUP?

```
SELECT [Phone Call ID], Created, [Client ID]
INTO ##todaysPhoneCalls
FROM dbo.vPhonecalls
WHERE Created >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY Created
```

Comment: Try using `between` in the `Where` clause... and put the earlier date before the current date. You do realize you are checking the phone call created date which looks like back in August which you won't get any hits.

Comment: Thanks @SS_DBA but I was only showing the top five results. I have made sure there are rows for the last 24 hours, and you made me think to create a temp table of them

Comment: Two questions: (1) What is the relation (if any) between the dates in the phone calls and assessments table? (2) Could you provide an example of a query and its result? It looks extremely strange that you get calls outside of the window you defined. Since you are selecting columns from the Calls table only, comment out the inner joins and the two ANDs and see if you are still getting records outside the time window (you should NOT).

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Creating a working example that demonstrates the issue, e.g. at [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) or [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), would help. (Remember to select SQL Server when fiddling.) Use an appropriate value in place of `GetDate()`, e.g. `declare @Now as DateTime = '2020-11-13T12:00:00';`, so that the problem occurs regardless of when the sample is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your `WHERE` clause look like this:

```
WHERE p.Created >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
    AND a.[Assessment Type] = 'Monitoring'
    AND c.[Client Type] = 'Case'
```

You can run this select:

```
select DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

to see what this is. Basically, it gets you a timestamp from 24 hours ago.

Comment: Thanks Casey. When I run `select DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())` it does get the last 24 hours. Sadly though, it the query still doesn't work, it still gets all phone calls.

I made another table of ONLY todays phone calls, and then tried that in the above query, and it STILL didn't work. How's it counting phone calls in a table that it isn't even querying? Is my COUNT or GROUP wrong? 

```SELECT [Phone Call ID], Created, [Client ID]
--INTO ##todaysPhoneCalls
FROM dbo.vPhonecalls
WHERE Created >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY Created```

Comment: Are you saying that this query: `SELECT * FROM vPhonecalls WHERE Created >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())` gets you all calls, even those older than 24 hours? Also, is `vPhonecalls` a View or a Table?

Comment: That's the thing, that SELECT statement above DOES WORK! haha. vPhonecalls is a view

Comment: I'm getting lost here. I'm not sure anymore what your problem is. Also, unless you have a REALLY good reason to use views (and you probably don't), I would not use them.

Comment: Thanks again! I really appreciate the help. I'm glad the syntax is correct. I'll try again with tables and report back